# Lazy loading doesn't work for me inEntity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to enable Lazy Loading on an EF4 context.

The code that is trying to load the data is:

```
using (IUnitOfWork uw = new EFUnitOfWork())
{
    foreach (Document doc in uw.Documents.All)
    {        
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Description: {1} Category: {2}", doc.Name, doc.Description, doc.DocumentCategory.Name);
    }
}
```

I am experimenting with the Repository and Unit Of Work patterns but as I understand it, the command below should work.

```
ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

The problem I have is when accessing doc.DocumentCategory.Name, I get a NullReferenceException.

Why isn't this data being loaded lazily?

If I have DocumentCategories loaded, the DocumentCategory property is resolved.

My Document class is defined as follows:

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {

    }

    public Document(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual int DocumentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public DocumentCategory DocumentCategory { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do *all* Documents have a DocumentCategory?  Just wonder incase the LazyLoading did attempt to retrieve the DocumentCategory for a given Document and found none, therefore returning null and causing your NullReferenceException.

Comment: Yes, DocumentCategoryId is a non-nullable field in the database and a foreign key exists between the tables.

Comment: Is the navigation property marked as virtual? Can you show us the definition of your Document class?

Comment: I've posted my Document class, the DocumentCategory property is not declared virtual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DocumentCategory property also needs to be marked as virtual in order for lazy loading to be supported. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer because you got there first in the question comments.

Answer (score 2):

Is Document.DocumentCategory declared as virtual? EF requires this, to generate a proxy type, that will actually perform the lazy loading when you access the property. (Otherwise EF does not know, when you access the property's value)

Also, if DocumentCategory is already virtual, there might be other properties that prevend EF from generating a proxy-type. Inspect a "Document" instance with the debugger to see, whether it is actually a proxy-type.